# Is the color red really appropriate for form validation errors?

Tags: forms, color, feedback, error-message

It seems to be taken for granted that the color red is appropriate to highlight errors. In the case of serious system errors, I agree. However, I'm having doubts that it's the right choice for user generated errors, like form validation.

It's common to see something like this:

[image: Red colored error message]

To me, this feels equivalent to blaming or yelling at the user. I've considered something like this instead:

[image: Yellow colored error message]

It feels like a message with a gentler tone even though the words are the same.

My opinion: Users don't need to *feel* like *they* caused an "error", and forms are already annoying enough as it is, especially when you've made a mistake or two (because after all, the user isn't *trying* to pass in an invalid email on purpose). It's just a small, correctable mistake - not a show-stopper.

System errors are a different thing: they aren't necessarily the user's fault, and they can really mean that something is broken or out of the user's control. Is there any reason why user generated errors should (or should not) be red?

* <sup>Note: I'm concerned about the colors, not necessarily the message text or icons.</sup>

Comment: I agree with you, basically - not sure if anything can be added to this to give you an 'answer'.

Comment: Have I assumed too much about "red" being the standard, or am I just being naive? I pretty much never see any deviation from it. Even on this site, validation errors are red: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2K4yA.png (I also find the "oops" very annoying, but that's another topic).

Comment: No, I think your assumptions are valid. I do recall seeing yellow/more neutral colours being used for validation errors on other sites (couldn't give you an example right now though). I'd associate red messages with being a more severe error. Whether or not this is a UX issue worth losing sleep over I don't know - or if it's something that can be researched easily or not.

Comment: I'd say it's pretty significant, as every site I run has validation errors. It's been a question I've had for a long time, so I'm not exactly losing sleep over it. There must be *something* to it if virtually every website uses red for these kinds of errors, or maybe it's just an oversight or habit. I think if it can be answered in a non-subjective way, this would be the place, right? If not, I'll leave it up to the community to close the question.

Comment: I didn't mean to tear you down or anything, of course this is the right place. :-) We'll wait and see what people come up with.

Comment: Red does seem like overkill. WARNING DANGER WARNING...your zip code has only 4 digits. Seriously?

On the flip side, people are used to it...

Comment: Red is the user convention so it's not going anywhere. That said, I agree that Red can feel heavy-handed. Perhaps use as little of it in the design as possible? Also the harshness of the Red can be offset by friendlier messaging. 

I like Scott Langham's idea on error messaging:
"Apologise.
Say what went wrong.
Say how to resolve it.
Be polite.
The message should be worded so that the application accepts responsibility for the problem. Never blame or criticize the user or make them think it's their fault."

Maybe, "Sorry, this email could not be validated. Please enter a valid email."

Comment: The yellow/ orange gives me the idea that I might be able to have this error on the page, and still be able to move forward. A warning, more than an error. That's coming from an old-head not ready to change with the 'times'.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think red is pretty much the convention in this context so you should use red for errors that need to be fixed before you can move on/send the form. Yellow is in general for warnings (eg. user perhaps should/could improve something, but it does not stop from proceeding). Yellow can be used with for example with one of those password strength thingies where bar shows how strong your password is: warn user when they give weak or very common password.

You should follow conventions (unless you have a very strong reason not to). To paraphrase [Jakob's Law of the Web User Experience](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/9605.html): people will spend most of their time somewhere else than on your website.

One important point to understand is that using conventional colors for errors is important because they make the errors more noticeable. User being annoyed by the color of error message is lot less of a problem than user not being able to complete the form because they didn't notice the error. At least in most cases.

Comment: You may be onto something here with yellow being warnings, I hadn't thought of that... Does make sense. Green = success. Yellow = warning but the program flow continues. Red = program flow halted.

Comment: What would be an example of a "warning"? Form validation errors can be fixed by the user (the email was not typed correctly) , while system errors can not (the email was not sent because of some system failure), so I feel there should be some distinction in the way they are presented or the user may not immediately be able to tell the difference ("Do I stop or continue? Do I have to fix something?").

Comment: Or are you just saying "Whether it's a good choice or not, red is already the standard, so just use it because that's what users expect"?

Comment: Very good point - although red may seem loud/angry you need to consider what happens if you tone down the colour of the most serious alert what impact that has on the lesser alerts? Does it make all alerts seem the same priority? Something like Red if something has gone wrong, Amber for general alerting (i.e. 'don't forget this').

Comment: "People will spend most of their time somewhere else than on your website" That's a great credo of UX.

Comment: @Madmartigan Red is already the standard, so just use it because users will understand what you are trying to communicate.  It's a good choice because they will understand you.  If they end up having to wade through a lot of these, thus getting a "blamed" feeling, you may have other problems that need to be fixed.

Answer (score 14):

Red for error messages and alerting to something that is of critical attention is pretty standard in Western society.

It is well used in operating systems, like Windows and OSX to use red for error, yellow for warning and green for success messages. This might be as subtle as just having a red “X” or a green tick, but they communicate the status of the message. Here are some Windows developer guidelines for colour use:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511283.aspx#meaning

You will even spot this on our roads. Red, yellow and green traffic lights. Red stop signs and no-entry signs. It is a cultural reference that we are very accustomed to.

[image: Stop sign]

In fact, during a recent round of usability testing, we had some messages incorrectly coloured as warnings when they should have been error red, and the feedback from the users was that these needed to be clearer and look more like an error message. In some instances specifying red was the preference.

If the context for red is required, users generally won’t feel shouted at or feel like they are made to look bad.

Unless you have a very good reason to not use red for error messages, you should conform to cultural customs and conventions. If you do decide to use something different, make sure that you test it to make sure it works.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know how well the stop light analogy works here, but this is great info nonetheless. Thanks for the informative link and your feedback, we'll be sticking to convention on this one.

Comment: Not a problem at all, happy to help. The stop light works in that it commands attention and has to be noticed, much like the user needs their attention and focus drawn to an error.

Comment: Why wouldn't the stop light analogy work here? This is all UX. These are design patterns we've adhered to for years intentionally.

Answer (score 2):

I think we're overlooking an important use-case: Some companies' brand colors are red/orange/pink, and in many cases we're associating brand color with errors is not good practice.

Color is just one design tool - in these cases using a warning/error icon that is not red (yellow/purple - something with relative contrast) is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience “Red” seems to be the color that most users associate with error. Most user environments utilize red for warning and respond accordingly. However, if the background or text does not contrast well, then using another color is acceptable.